# Can we create volumes inside docker container

Tags: centos, docker, volumes

I am trying to create logical volumes (like `/dev/sdb` or so) inside a running centos docker container. If anyone has tried doing so successfully, please help!

After installing lvm2 and running lvmetad, when I tried creating a VG, I get the below error:

> bash-4.2# lvcreate -L 2G stackit
>
> /dev/mapper/control: open failed: Operation not permitted
>
> Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
>
> Check that device-mapper is available in the kernel.
>
> striped: Required device-mapper target(s) not detected in your
>   kernel.
>
> Run `lvcreate --help' for more information.

Comment: Could you describe why you are trying to do this? At first glance, the question sounds like it arises from a misunderstanding of what Docker is.

Comment: @sheldonh I am trying to port a legacy application as a docker container. The application works on a specific partition/volume. Trying to make it available to the application from within a docker container.

Comment: Why not use the [-v command](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) to start the container?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what exactly what you are trying to do, but docker containers by default run with restricted privileges.

Try adding (old way)

```
--privileged=true
```

Or (new way)

```
--cap-add=ALL
```

To give the container full privileges.   Then you can narrow down which capabilities you actually need to give the container.